# Pushing app to heroku problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, heroku

I am trying to push my app to heroku and I get the following message:

```
$ heroku create
Creating electric-meadow-15..... done
Created http://electric-meadow-15.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:electric-meadow-1
5.git

$ git push heroku master

 !  No such app as fierce-fog-63

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It's weird that I am getting this now, I have pushed the app to heroku many times without issue.  the especially weird thing is, `fierce-fog-63` is an old app that I made and deleted a long time ago.  Why is it now that heroku is trying to push to this app that doesn't exist anymore, especially when I have created a new one?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Type this and I think you'll see the problem:

```
git remote -v
```

Fix it like this:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:electric-meadow-15.git
```

Comment: that worked...but now it is giving me this message:

$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1652, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
fatal: object 91f5d3ee9e2edcd42e961ed2eb254d5181cbc734 inconsistent object lengt
h (476 vs 8985)
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:floating-stone-94.git'

Comment: In case anyone's issue is [renaming an existing app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

Comment: @Adam Wiggins It would be useful if you explain your solutions, what those commands do , and why it worked.

Comment: This worked for the same problem with the Python app. Except I also had to heroku create after git remote rm heroku (my problem was probably slightly different).

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the second error you posted "failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:floating-stone-94.git' " (with a different app name) and i got rid of it by doing the following:

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku create
```

you should see a line that says 'Git remote heroku added'. Also

```
git remote -v
```

should now have the correct app.

Comment: Won't heroku create make an entire new project on heroku?

Answer (score 5):

For all the people who this does not work, check your **~/.heroku/credentials**

If the email or token does not match the account, you won't see your apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you got here and think you have a similar problem but all of the other stuff suggested does not work you might want to try:

```
heroku restart
```