# pushing to heroku git error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have created a brand new heroku app, beforehand i deleted the old .git file from my app's directory and created a new one with the usual steps:

```
git init, git add ., git commit -m "new git"
```

all of which worked fine.  I then created a new app like so and got the following error:

```
$ heroku create
Creating glowing-summer-56.... done
Created http://glowing-summer-56.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:glowing-summer-56.
git
Git remote heroku added

$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1553, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
fatal: object 91f5d3ee9e2edcd42e961ed2eb254d5181cbc734 inconsistent object lengt
h (387 vs 8985)
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:glowing-summer-56.git'
```

This is strange to me, as it is a brand new .git file.  How can I get rid of this without cleaning up each damaged object? Is there a way to just delete the git file and start anew? I'm not using this git file for *anything* other than pushing to heroku.

Also I should note that I am using Cygwin on windows and my git version is 1.6.6.1

I've come across this error before and fixed it, I just honestly can't remember how.

Finally, using git fsck --full yields nothing :(

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947190/pushing-app-to-heroku-problem ? I would recommend using msysgit rather than Cygwin though, for git-related operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i seemingly fixed this with: git reset

Comment: I would run `git fsck` afterwards, just in case that the error is only hidden by something other but still present.