# Git push vs. git push heroku master

Tags: git, github, heroku, commit, push

I just moved from a pc laptop to a Mac, and I've noticed a curious difference in how my git commands respond.

Before, I would do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "These are my new changes"
git push # This would update my repo on github
{enter password}
git push heroku master # This would push to my app on heroku
{enter password}
```

Now, when I do `git push`, the app just deploys on Heroku without pushing to my Github repo.

How can I ensure I'm updating both places?

### Edit

Thanks for your two answers! I appreciate the clarification of the difference between `git push` and `git push heroku master`, in that `git push` is pushing towards origin, which in my case, it seems, is Heroku.

How can I change the settings so that they work as before? i.e. I want `git push` to now push to my repo on Github, and I want `git push heroku master` to push to Heroku. The former currently pushes straight to Heroku, bypassing Github completely.

Comment: I had a very similar problem and found this to be very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947190/pushing-app-to-heroku-problem

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get the behavior you want, you'll need to remove the existing remotes and re-add them:

```
git remote show origin # copy down the heroku URL
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin [github URL]
git remote add heroku [heroku URL]
```

Comment: Or `git remote rename origin heroku` and then `get remote add origin <github-url>` instead of writing down.

Answer (score 2):

The `git push` command by default pushes to a remote called `origin`. This usually points to the place where you cloned your repository from, but you can change it later.

The `git remote show` command will show a list of all remotes. Then, `git remote show origin` and `git remote show heroku` will detail how each is configured.

You can manage and change the URL for each remote using the [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the command `git push`--that is, omitting the arguments--means that git is going to have to use the defaults, which would be your first remote repository (commonly named 'origin') as the destination, and your local master branch as the source. In your case, I'm guessing that you cloned the project from GitHub in the first place, which makes your default remote be GitHub.

When you specify the arguments `git push heroku master`, you are explicitly saying to push your local master branch to the remote named heroku -- thus, GitHub is not updated with this command.

(Perhaps heroku was your first/default remote on the PC, and when you moved to the Mac the `origin` remote was the clone from GitHub?)