# Trouble pushing basic Ruby on Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I was working through the first chapter of the Rails Tutorial. I pushed first_app to heroku. At first I was getting the sqlite3 error (I think). But, I edited the gemfile and pushed it up to heroku again. But, I don't get the same page as on: http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:1.4.3 (I think it's supposed to look like Figure 1.11 in section 1.4.3)

Instead, I get this: http://blooming-samurai-546.heroku.com/

It just says: 
Heroku | Welcome to your new app! 
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.

I did something wrong right? Any ideas what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your git console try:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Initial commit"
git push heroku
```

It looks like you pushed to heroku with nothing so it created an empty directory.

Comment: Success!!! Actually, just before I saw your answer, I found this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947190/pushing-app-to-heroku-problem, so I removed the old project and added the new one as in that thread. But then my app was "crashing". Then, I saw your answer and did what you said. Don't fully understand it, but it's working now.

Comment: I didn't know you could use add and message together like '-am'. That will save me a few keystrokes throughout the day.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was very frustrated by it. What solved the issue for me was moving 
`gem 'sqlite3'`
into the block following 
`group :development, :test` 
in the Gemfile.
After that, no longer saw these kinds of messages:

```
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
...
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

in terminal after typing `git push heroku` or `git push heroku master`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Can’t argue with success.

However, before pushing the master with $ git push heroku master some folks may need to run the following command:

$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-heroku-url-goes-here.git

as discussed in the “Git Remotes and Heroku” section currently at:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git