# Push Rails 3.2 site seen as PHP site by Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've added a few details at the top to explain how I got where I am.

I've created a Rails 3.2 application and I'm pushing it to Heroku. I've pushed several sites to Heroku so I've done this a fair number of times. However, I've never seen this.

I started out with my normal "heroku create" command, then "git push heroku master". When I ran that it returned with the message "No such app as..."

Based on what I saw on Stack Overflow here [Pushing app to Heroku problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947190/pushing-app-to-heroku-problem) I then entered "git remote -v", saw two heroku items, entered "git remote rm heroku" to remove these items. I re-ran the "heroku create", "git push heroku master" and the site did push to Heroku, but Heroku thinks it's a PHP site.

There isn't a single line of PHP code in my entire app. In fact the string "PHP" don't exist anywhere.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your gem file named Gemfile and not gemfile? Seen that cause issues before with Heroku. It uses your direction/file structure to know its a rails app and it is case sensitive.

Comment: It's named "Gemfile" which is the same I've used for every site I've successfully pushed to Heroku

Comment: Humm, might be looking for config/application.rb too. Looking at the app pack it checks to see if that file exists to detect rails. If not maybe post the output of tree /path/to/yourapp

Comment: The site is a prototype that I scaffolded. So config/application.rb is there. I'm not sure what you mean by tree /path/to/yourapp

Comment: Do you perhaps have an index.php in the root folder?

Comment: tree is a command line tool. Most operating systems have it. Shows your full directory structure. Figured I could see what was different from it. But it sounds like something else is going on anywho. Not sure what off hand. Maybe someone else will soon =)

Comment: There is no index.php file at the root of my site. In fact the string "php" doesn't exist in the entire project anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I deleted the git directory, posted it to a new repository on github, cloned it into a new directory and then created a new Heroku site to push it to.